# Sql join condition when many similar columns needs to be considered

Tags: sql

I have 25 columns namely *indicator_1*, *indicator_2* and so on... untill *indicator_25*.

Any one of the indicator columns can only have a not null value.

We need to find the not null column and the value and join with another table using this particular indicator column in the join condition.

Please, suggest me a good method.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?  Are you saying that it will always be the case that only one of the 25 columns would have a non `NULL` value?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard `COALESCE()` function:

```
...
WHERE 
    COALESCE(indicator_1, indicator_2, indicator_3, indicator_4, indicator_5, ....) = AnotherTable.Indicator
```

Comment: same in Oracle there the same function, but you have to be careful, optimizer will not use index !

Comment: `COALESCE` is actually ANSI SQL, and supported by most dbms products.